# Store Custom Exception Messages in File or Class

Tags: java, exception

If I throw a Illegal Argument Exception, I also want to pass the reason like `"Value can not be negative"` or something like that. I don´t like the idea of having code like this:

```
public void setAge(int age) {
    if (age >= 0) {
        this.age = age;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age can not be negative");
    }
}
```

I was thinking of something like

```
public static final String AGE_CAN_NOT_BE_NEGATIVE = "Age can not be negative";
```

in another class, to store all custom exception messages in one file. This way I can also use the message in unit tests, to see, if the right exception is thrown, when I use the function. I also can reuse the messages. Same goes for custom exceptions, where i would rather store the message in another file.

The thing is: The class can get very big, if there are a lot of custom messages for the exceptions.

What is your approach with a lot of custom messages?

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach, which the team where I’m working in uses, is to create custom exceptions. So, following your example:

```
public void setAge(int age) {
    if (cost >= 0) {
        this.age = age;
    } else {
        throw new AgeIllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

...

private class AgeIllegalArgumentException extends IllegalArgumentException {
    public AgeIllegalArgumentException() {
        super("Age can not be negative");
    }
}
```

In this way you can check in your tests that the right exception is thrown. We tend to have these custom exceptions scoped for each class, but that’s a matter of taste depending on the granularity you wish to have. If the above was for a `Person` class, we’d have the following:

```
private class PersonIllegalArgumentException extends IllegalArgumentException {
    public PersonIllegalArgumentException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

In the above you can have a static `String` if you need access to the error messages, too, combining both solutions.

Comment: I was also thinking about this, but i try to avoid custom exceptions wherever i can, as it bloads the ammount of classes. A `IllegalArgumentException` is something, every developer is familiar with and as the stacktrace prints out the class, where it was thrown, you should find your coding/usage error quick enough. I would use the message for the GUI for example. And still, i would rather define the messages in another file and then create a custom exception with these strings.

Comment: As usual, it’s something that needs to be thought out first. I’m not advocating for this pattern everywhere, but we have parts in our code where I think it’s justified. Also, it helps with testing, as you can check that certain parts of the code throw a specific exception.